# Discord.py Bot messaging channel issue

Tags: python, variables

I started making a bot on discord using discord.py and I have one issue that I just can't fix. The goal was to make a command that makes the bot message a certain channel with a certain message. Here is the code

```
@commands.has_any_role("Phantom","XX")
async def msg(ctx,*, Msg = None):
   await ctx.send(f"Please give the channel ID. You can do this by saying ``.ID (IDhere)``")
   @client.command()
   async def ID(ctx,*, ID = 0):
       message = Msg
       channel = client.get_channel(ID)
       await channel.send(message)
       await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Message sent")
```

On the first time I run the whole command it works as intended on the second time as soon as i say the .msg command i get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Command ID is already registered.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the command before use it, so the solution would be to define to command at the top of your program so when it starts it simply loads all the command you are going to use.

Here is what you are looking for : [How to fix "discord.errors.ClientException: Command kick is already registered." error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55656497/13071340)